# Aligning form controls vertically in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, row

With a lot of help on this site and some effort of my own I finally resolved all column issues.  Now I would like to know if there is a `Bootstrap 3` way (no custom CSS) to align different form controls (Bottstrap's own as well from 3rd-parties, like `JQuery UI`) **vertically**.

> Can **`<form>`** itself control the **height** (or **vertical spacing**) of all its children?

Below is my example that shows real column configurations and mark-up of different form controls that purposefully do not have the same height.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">  
            <div class='row'>
                <form role="form">
                    <div class='col-lg-3'>
                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12'><div class="form-group thumbnail">Widget 1<br></br>Line #2 for 1</div></div>
                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12'><div class="form-group"><h2>Widget 2</h2></div></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='col-lg-3'>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12' ><div class="form-group thumbnail"><label for="widget3">Label for 3:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Widget 3" id="widget3"/></div></div>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12'><div class="form-group thumbnail"><p>Widget 4</p></div>
                    </div></div>

                    <div class='col-lg-3'>
                        <div class=' col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12'><div class="form-group"><span class="thumbnail">Widget 5</span></div></div>
                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12'><div class="input group"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Wdget 6"/><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span></div></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>    
        </div>    

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScripts -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**Here is**](http://jsfiddle.net/PfA9A/) the same as JSFiddle.

One more thing. In the above example (but not in my real layout) `glyphicon` `add-on` does not appear to the right of `<input>` element but stacks underneath instead.  What did I do wrong here? Is there a typo I can't notice?
**EDIT** (0405/14) my "`input-group`" typo was pinpointed by `Arbel` on 04/02/14. **This is no longer a problem.**

**Additional Questions** (04/03/14):

1. What pushes `Widget 3` to the right on `md` view?
2. How can I force `Widget 4` and `Widget 5` to swap positions on `md` view (when they are in different rows? My attempt to add `pull-right` class to `Widget 4` did not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

For vertical spacing: From [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

> Components throughout Bootstrap make use of some default variables for
>   setting common values.

So you will need to edit those values.

For the add-on, on the last row, change `<div class="input group">` to `<div class="input-group">`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/PfA9A/1/

Comment: Thanks for the add-on solution. I knew it must be a typo. As far as Bootstrap goes, do you mean that I will have to configure every component separately, or can I at least do it on `<form-group>` level?

Comment: You can recompile the CSS using LESS and change what you need, or you can simply add custom CSS AFTER when the Bootstrap CSS is loaded and target the specific classes with the modifications you need. e.g. `.container .form-group .form-control {padding: 10px 30px;}`

Comment: I'm not following you. Padding is added around an element. How would I know how much to add with responsive design (i.e on different screen sizes)?

Comment: That was an example, based on your needs you can go with percentages.

Comment: If I'm dealing with components of different heights that need to align vertically on every screen size, how would I know the exact padding?

Answer (score 1):

For your additional questions, I have updated your JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PfA9A/17/).

1 - The reason that Widget 2 was staying to the right is because you needed to clear the floats that Bootstrap uses when you use the `col-xx-xx` classes. I did this by inserting `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` between each of your larger divs containing the `col-lg-3` class. Alternatively, you could add the class `row` to these divs, as it clears the floats for you, but does cause changes in margin. That would give you `class="row col-lg-3"` on those divs.

2 - This might not be the "best" solution, but you can duplicate your Widget 4 and Widget 5 and make use of Bootstrap's `hidden-xx` and `visible-xx` classes. I put Widget 5 with `class="visible-md"` under Widget 4, adding `hidden-md` to its class. I did the complete opposite where Widget 5 was, with the extra modification of Widget 4's `pull-right` to a `pull-left` since you want it left of Widget 6.

UPDATE:

Alternate solution for 2. I wrote some jQuery/Javascript that will swap the html of Widget 4 and Widget 5 when the screen gets into medium size (992-1200 based on Bootstrap documentation).

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PfA9A/29/)

```
var widget4 = $('#widget4').html();
var widget5 = $('#widget5').html();

resizeCheck(); //Run on load incase screen loads in medium size

$(window).on('resize', resizeCheck); //Run on window resize

function resizeCheck() {
    var width = $(window).width();

    if(width >= 992 && width < 1200) {
        mediumWidth();
    } else {
        restoreWidgets();
    }
}

function mediumWidth() {    
    $('#widget4').html(widget5);
    $('#widget5').html(widget4);
}

function restoreWidgets() {
    $('#widget4').html(widget4);
    $('#widget5').html(widget5);
}
```

Comment: RE: `visible`.  These components in real life are input elements bound to model by AngularJS, so if I duplicate the fields it would lead to duplicate field population. I would really prefer not to go this route.

Comment: That is understandable. Hopefully #1 helped some, I will see if I can find a better solution for your 2nd question.

Comment: FYI: RE: `clear: both` - The same can be achieved by placing `<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>` between "*rows*"

Comment: I added an alternative to #2. It still may not be the best solution but it does keep you from having duplicate widgets.

Answer (score 0):

As the class used by u takes the width as 100% the glyphicon comes on the next line, so to solve this add a style="width:80%;float:left" & class="form-control" into the input tag (for the textbox) and then put the glyphicon after the tag...I hope this helps

Comment: Please see the real reason for the add-on problem in `Arbel`'s answer.  It was actually a typo on my part.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PfA9A/6/

```
      <div class="container">  
<div class='row'>
    <form role="form">
        <div class='col-lg-3'>
          <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12'><div class="form-group thumbnail">Widget 1<br/>Line #2 for 1</div></div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12'><div class="form-group"><h2>Widget 2</h2></div></div>
        </div>

        <div class='col-lg-3'>
                <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12' ><div class="form-group thumbnail"><label for="widget3">Label for 3:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Widget 3" id="widget3"/></div></div>
                <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12 pull-right'><div class="form-group thumbnail"><p>Widget 4</p></div>
        </div></div>

        <div class='col-lg-3'>
            <div class=' col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="thumbnail">Widget 5</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12'>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Wdget 6"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

glyphicon problem fixed you had a typo in form-group.

Comment: What is your fiddle supposed to show? My "input-group" typo was identified by `Arbel` 3 days ago.

Comment: yeah didnt see that sorry. but i did remove a extra span tag where you added glyphicon.. there was no need for that.